# Iterate an operation over groups while considering multiple columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
raw_data = {'cities': ['LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston'], 
        'location': ['pub', 'dive', 'club', 'disco', 'cinema', 'cafe', 'diner', 'bowling','supermarket', 'pizza', 'icecream', 'music'], 
        'distance': ['0', '50', '100', '5', '75', '300', '20', '40', '70', '400', '2000', '2'], 
        'score': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['cities', 'location', 'distance', 'score'])
df
```

**Now I am trying to write a loop such that for each city, the 'location' with the highest 'score' is returned within an iterating 'distance' window.**

I.e. the location with the highest score every 100 units.

How can I write a loop to do this?

[image: df]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't LA dive be chosen as it has 94 score?

Comment: Yes - typo, will fix.

Comment: don't half of those have distance > 100?

Comment: Yes, I meant a window of 100, i.e. the location with the highest score every 100 units. So if the LA club distance was 125, then dive AND club would be returned (assuming 100 unit window starting at 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**This appears to be working:**

```
df['distance'] = pd.to_numeric(df['distance'])
df['bin100'] = pd.cut(df['distance'], np.arange(0, 2001, 100), include_lowest=True, labels=False)
df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['cities', 'bin100'], sort=False)['score'].idxmax(), :-1]
```

**Thanks to @manwithfewneeds for providing the logic applied here.**

For some DataFrames, `df.loc` may be necessary to avoid index out-of-bounds error:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['cities', 'bin100'], sort=False)['score'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a fake column to group distances within a range per 100 units.  I first set any distance that has a value of 0 a value of 1, then divide by 100 and round up using numpy ceil, that gets a range of integers, for example anything between 0 and 100 kilometers would be grouped together (a value of 1 in the fake column)  After that I groupby city and the fake column, take the max index of the score in each group, and locate it back in the orignal dataframe.  Lastly, we don't want that fake column in the final output so I slice all the columns up until the last with iloc (:-1):

```
df['t'] = pd.Series(pd.np.where(df['distance'].eq('0'), 1, 
                    df['distance'])).astype(int).div(100).apply(pd.np.ceil)
df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['cities', 't'], sort=False)['score'].idxmax(), :-1]

print(df)

     cities  location distance  score
1        LA      dive       50     94
6   Chicago     diner       20     94
5   Chicago      cafe      300     25
11   Boston     music        2     70
9    Boston     pizza      400     70
10   Boston  icecream     2000     62
```

Comment: The output is correct! Do you mind explaining a bit more the approach here? These two lines are difficult for me to follow.

Comment: Tried my best to explain.  If you want you can dissect the code I wrote and see what's happening bit by bit in your console.

Comment: So I ran this on my actual DataFrame and I'm having multiple rows returned within the same "city" with a "distance" within 100 units of eachother. The function should only return the top scoring row per 100 units...

Comment: Can you post an example output?

Comment: Also check your dtypes with df.dtypes.  My solution works if distance is a string like in your example data.  If it's a numeric type, like int, or float, you can take out some of the logic in the first line, ie. replace with:  `df['t'] = pd.Series(pd.np.where(df['distance'].eq(0), 1, df['distance'])).div(100).apply(pd.np.ceil)`

Comment: distance dtype is int64, cities dtype is object, score dtype is float64. to check your function, I'm passing in my df and then grouping it by cities, checking the size of a random city, df_grouped.agg(np.size).sample(n=5), and then looking at a particular city with dfgrouped.get_group(). many rows with almost identical distances are being returned.

Comment: Nice job, good fix.  I was going to type up a possible fix but looks like you got it

Comment: I'm getting the error - IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds - any suggestions? EDIT: I think I need to make sure lowest bin is 1, not 0.

Comment: I believe I've fixed this issue by switching to .loc instead of .iloc: .loc method directly selects based on index values of any rows. And not slicing out last column. Does that sound right?

Comment: iloc is purely integer index based.  You can get rows and columns based on their respective indexes by integer.  Loc is label based.  So you can specify the column label instead of its integer index.

Comment: Both iloc and loc can use boolean indexing for row values.  In other words, a slice of the dataframe will be returned if the condition is true.

Comment: Changing the last line to this fixed the issue on my actual DataFrame, i believe because I'm trying to index based on label - df = df.loc[df.groupby(['cities', 'bin100'], sort=False)['score'].idxmax()]

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're after is:

df['distance'] = df['distance'].astype(int)

```
windows=list(range(0,max_distance,100))


new = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(windows)-1):
    new = new.append(df[(df['distance'] >= windows[i]) & (df['distance'] < windows[i+1])].groupby(['cities'],as_index=False)['score'].max())
```

which outputs:

```
   cities  score
0   Boston     70
1  Chicago     94
2       LA     94
0       LA     57
0  Chicago     25
0   Boston     70
0   Boston     62
```

but I'm not sure how to keep the distance column corresponding to these cities/scores values and sort by these distances

Comment: This is very close - how can it be modified to return a new df?

Comment: like a new df for each? or these results all in one df with another column for window?

Comment: a new df containing all the rows that are the top scoring per window, just like the output but not a print statement. The code under "output:" above is exactly what I am looking for, but as a new df.

Comment: can obviously split the code into segments if you want..but it works as a long one liner lol

Comment: I may be missing something but I think your last edit "new =" is now returning every row of the original df.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198397/discussion-between-confuseddolphin-and-derek-eden).

Comment: totally misread the question..but edited the code to give you what you want..but not sure how to maintain the distance column

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
#df.distance=pd.to_numeric(df.distance)
df.sort_values('score').groupby([df.cities,pd.cut(df.distance,range(0,1000,100))]).tail(1).sort_index()
     cities  location  distance  score
1        LA      dive        50     94
5   Chicago      cafe       300     25
6   Chicago     diner        20     94
9    Boston     pizza       400     70
10   Boston  icecream      2000     62
11   Boston     music         2     70
```

Comment: In my df this line appears to be removing every row with a distance value of 0

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
lS=df.groupby(['cities'])['score'].idxmax().tolist()
lD=(df.groupby(['cities'])['distance'].apply(lambda x:x>100))
df2=df.loc[lS].append(df[lD]).drop_duplicates().sort_values(['cities'],ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
    cities  location    distance    score
0   LA      dive        50          94
1   Chicago diner       20          94
2   Chicago cafe        300         25
3   Boston  pizza       400         70
4   Boston  icecream    2000        62
```

Comment: This returns: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match